Confusion Regarding IAM Role Credentials in AWS Partner Central Sandbox Testing Documentation
I’m following the AWS documentation for testing in a sandbox environment for AWS Partner Central APIs, specifically the steps outlined here: Testing in a sandbox - AWS Partner Central API Reference.
The documentation mentions the following steps:

Create an IAM role:  Create an IAM role in the AWS account linked with your AWS Partner Central account.
Assign Policy: Assign the specified policy to the IAM role.
Use IAM role credentials: Use the credentials (secret key and access key) of this IAM role in your solution to perform the API actions.

As far as I know, IAM roles do not have long-term access key and secret access key credentials. Instead, roles are assumed, providing temporary security credentials via AWS STS (Security Token Service). IAM users are the ones that have permanent access keys.
My Confusion:

How can I use the “credentials (secret key and access key)” of an IAM role when roles don’t have such credentials?
Is the documentation suggesting that I should assume the IAM role to obtain temporary credentials, and then use those credentials?
Alternatively, should I create an IAM user, assign the policy to that user, and use the user’s access key and secret access key?

What I’ve Tried:

I understand how to assume an IAM role using AWS STS to get temporary credentials, but the documentation doesn’t mention assuming the role or using STS.
I’ve considered creating an IAM user instead, but I’m concerned this might not align with best practices or the intent of the documentation.

Questions:

What is the correct way to proceed based on this documentation?
Is there an error or oversight in the documentation regarding the use of IAM role credentials?
Should I be assuming the IAM role to get temporary credentials, and if so, how does this integrate with the AWS Partner Central APIs in the sandbox environment?

Any guidance or clarification would be greatly appreciated!
